# How to select distinct when i have multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with multiple rows in two columns.

```
# Column_A # Column B
# 1        # photo01
# 1        # photo02
# 1        # photo03
# 2        # video01
# 2        # video02
# 3        # music01
# 3        # music02
# 3        # music03
```

So when i'm using `SELECT DISTINCT Column_A` i have 3 records: 1, 2, 3.
When i'm using `SELECT DISTINCT Column_A, Column_B` i have all records.
I want not duplicated rows from Column_A with first row from Column_B, 1:1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_product, (SELECT photos FROM my_table) 
FROM my_table
ORDER BY ID_product
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Expected result:

```
# Column_A # Column B
# 1        # photo01
# 2        # video01
# 3        # music01
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select column_a, min(column_b)
from t
group by column_a;
```

If you want an arbitrary match, you can use window functions stead:

```
select column_a, column_b
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column_a order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```